# Unable to import ftputil in Python

Tags: python, import, ftputil

I am trying to delete ftp file using Spyder (python 3.8), but one of the import "**ftputil**" is not working. Error code looks like

> import ftputil ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ftputil'

**code**

```
 #! /usr/bin/python
 import time
 import ftputil
 host = ftputil.FTPHost('host', 'username', 'password')
 mypath = 'ftp_dir'
 now = time.time()
 host.chdir(mypath)
 names = host.listdir(host.curdir)
 for name in names:
   if host.path.getmtime(name) < (now - (3600)):
     if host.path.isfile(name):
        host.remove(name)
 host.close()
```

Can we use another import, if it is not working.

Comment: do you use Anaconda platform?

Comment: I am working with Spyder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to install it using this instruction:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ftputil
```

for more info check this [page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ftputil)